# Firefox window is distorted/broken after changing from fullscreen

Tags: 12.04, compiz, firefox

I accidentally dropped firefox from full-screen to half-screen and set it to fullscreen again, but when i open firefox, it... well, it does not look very ok...

[image: openinge firefox in unity]

well, when i click on the upper bar, it looks like that:
[image: not completely fullscreen]

here it seems that firefox is drawn too far left, when i enter an url, it does not show until it is long enough... after another click in the bar, it is really full-screen...

how can i get rid of this problem?

Comment: You've tried restarting?  Can you reproduce the problem every time, or is it just occasionally?

Comment: this problem is everytime...

Comment: Check if the problem is with Firefox by using another browser.  If it is and you are updated to the latest version, consider going back to an earlier version.

Comment: ok, seems like it is a problem with firefox.. chromium shows in full-screen from the beginning

Comment: after deinstalling firefox, removing the ~/.mozilla folder and reinstalling it, firefox works again :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Removing Firefox, deleting the ~/.mozilla directory and reinstalling firefox did the trick, now it works again :)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try closing the process or restarting ubuntu, if you haven't yet. Your problem might be only temporary.

Comment: it's not just now, it is everytime, i have this problem for nearly a week now